# Able to write events to read-only calendar via API

Tags: office365, office365api

Here is what I believe to be a bug in the Calendar REST API - but I'm hoping to find a workaround.

In short, I'm able to POST calendar events to a read-only calendar via the API without error. The odd part is that the 365 UI knows that the calendar is read only, and wont allow edits via the UI.

This causes problems with our sync, as when the original calendar publishes again all the new events get deleted. My question is how can I know for certain that the calendar I'm writing to has proper write permissions (as the UI does), and secondly, is it a bug that I can write via API but not through UI?

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Grab a public, read-only ical calendar address. Eg [this](http://webcal://bishopbradyathletics.com/main/team/id/3620078)
2. In 365, right click 'My calendars' and 'open calendar' [image]
3. Paste in the address from (1) in the 'internet calendar' field. Calendar should appear under 'My Calendars'. **Note that you are unable to create events for this calendar through the UI**
4. Use `GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/calendars` to get the newly added calendar's ID
5. Use `POST https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/calendars/[CALENDAR_ID]/events` to create an event to the new calendar.

**Expected behaviour**
Like the UI, the API does not allow you to write to this calendar.

**Actual behaviour**
Successful creation, 201 created returned. Surprise! After some time (4-6 hours), the newly created event will be deleted. This causes issues if you are syncing this calendar, as the deletion will propagate to whichever client is syncing with that calendar.

[image]

Comment: Let me investigate this and get back to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this. I looked into this, and unfortunately there's not *currently* a good answer for this. It's something we're working on improving to make the API more consistent with Outlook and OWA. Unfortunately I don't have any timeline to share.

Basically, when you subscribe to an internet calendar, a secondary calendar is created in the mailbox. It isn't truly read-only, but Outlook and OWA know that it's intended for syncing with the internet calendar and won't let you create items there. That logic is all on the client, not on the server, which is why it behaves the way it does today.

The event gets deleted the next time the sync process with the webcal URL is kicked off since it doesn't exist in the ICS pulled down from the webcal link.

As a workaround, if you're willing to dip into the `/beta` endpoint, you could retrieve the `PidTagExtendedFolderFlags` property on the calendar. That's a binary property, so you'd need to do some parsing on it to get at the data. The format is documented in [MS-OXOCFG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee237591(v=exchg.80).aspx). You'd need to parse for the [sub-property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff367971(v=exchg.80).aspx) with `Id` equal to 0x01, then test the `Data` as a bitmask for the 0x40 bit. If it's set, the folder should be treated as read-only.

To get this property, you need to expand the `SingleValueExtendedProperties` on the `Calendar` entities, like so:

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/calendars?
$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'Binary 0x36da')
```

This will return something like:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "Id": "AAMkAGRm...AAA=",
      "Name": "Calendar",
      "Color": "Auto",
      "ChangeKey": "nxdFEDVaMUqvOVUO3592PQAAFmsEKg==",
      "SingleValueExtendedProperties": [
        {
          "PropertyId": "Binary 0x36da",
          "Value": "AQQAABAA"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": "AAMkAGRm...AAA=",
      "Name": "Internet Calendar",
      "Color": "Auto",
      "ChangeKey": "nxdFEDVaMUqvOVUO3592PQAAFmsELQ==",
      "SingleValueExtendedProperties": [
        {
          "PropertyId": "Binary 0x36da",
          "Value": "AQRAJRAC"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The values for those properties are base64-encoded binary blobs. If you decode them, you get something like:

- For Calendar: 010400001000
- For Internet Calendar: 010440251002

Interpreting those per the format, we have:

```
Id: 0x01
Cb: 0x04
Data: 0x02102540
```

The 0x40 bit is set in the `Data` field, so that one is read-only.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does this mean that there is _no_ way to detect if a calendar is syncing to an internet calendar via the API? Surely if OWA knows that it is, the data must be coming from somewhere (ie. the server)?

This is causing a massive issue whereby if a user selects one of these calendars and we sync using the provided endpoint [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#Syncevents), all of the added events from our side come back as 'deletion events' after the sync period, leading to a data loss scenario.

Comment: The property OWA reads is a binary MAPI property. I tried and I can access it via the beta endpoint. Adding details to my answer.

Comment: I'm using the PidTagExtendedFolderFlags (0x36da) property as you described and it does work (still in 2022...) to identify read-only calendars. However, I didn't find proper documentation for this. Isn't there a better way of testing for read-only on shared calendars?