# EWS Filter out the US holiday and birthday events in Outlook calendar

Tags: outlook

I'm working on calendar sync for two accounts. But when I do this, US Holiday and Birthday Events are duplicating. How to restrict this duplication using the EWS filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out Birthday calendars by excluding any calendars with a FolderClass of "IPF.Appointment.Birthday". With Holiday calendars the PidTagExtendedFolderFlags
property is used to mark the Folder a ReadOnly see [Able to write events to read-only calendar via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34163719/able-to-write-events-to-read-only-calendar-via-api) so you should be able to use that to exclude any of those calendars.